# How to determine the damping coefficient from data in Matlab or other graphing software

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, gnuplot

I recently did an experiment where I measured the output signal of an RLC circuit which behaves exactly like a damped free harmonic oscillator. I want to to dermine the damping ratio from the data. My first idea was to use a decaying exponential fit on the enveloppe, as depicted in the following Figure.[image: Fit and plot]

After many hours of despair, I managed to use the Curve Fitting tool provided by Matlab to add an exponential fit, but I had to select manually the peaks to take into account. Is there any way to achieve this same result but with code ?

I mean, I know there has to be a way, but I've been struggling for more time than should be legally permitted, so If any kind soul could help me with a script, I'd warmheartedly welcome it. I can use either Gnuplot, python or Matlab.

Thanks in advance

Here is a link to the full data file, since SO doesn't let me dump the whole content here
[data file link](https://easyupload.io/0zfkjz)

```
time[0] Y[0]    time[1] Y[1]
  747979    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747979    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747979    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747979    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747979    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747980    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747980    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747980    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747980    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747980    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747981    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747981    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747981    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747981    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747981    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747982    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747982    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747982    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747982    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747982    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747983    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747983    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747983    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747983    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747983    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747984    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747984    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747984    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747984    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747984    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747985    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747985    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747985    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747985    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747985    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747986    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747986    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747986    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747986    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747986    -3.840462E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747987    -4.694474E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747987    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747987    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747987    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747987    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747988    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747988    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747988    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747988    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747988    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747989    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747989    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747989    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747989    -3.840462E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747989    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747990    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747990    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747990    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747990    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747990    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747991    -3.840462E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747991    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747991    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747991    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747991    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747992    -3.840462E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747992    -3.840462E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747992    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747992    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747992    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747993    -4.694474E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747993    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747993    -4.267468E-1    -5.114054E-1
  747993    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747993    -4.267468E-1    -4.689731E-1
  747994    4.699659E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747994    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747994    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747994    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747994    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747995    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747995    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747995    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747995    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747995    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747996    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747996    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747996    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747996    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747996    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747997    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747997    5.553671E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747997    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747997    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747997    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747998    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747998    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747998    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747998    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747998    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747999    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  747999    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  747999    5.553671E-1 -4.265408E-1
  747999    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  747999    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748000    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748000    5.553671E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748000    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  748000    5.553671E-1 -4.689731E-1
  748000    5.126665E-1 -4.689731E-1
  748001    5.553671E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748001    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748001    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748001    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748001    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748002    5.553671E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748002    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748002    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748002    5.553671E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748002    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748003    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748003    5.126665E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748003    5.553671E-1 -4.265408E-1
  748003    5.553671E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748003    5.126665E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748004    5.126665E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748004    5.126665E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748004    5.126665E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748004    5.126665E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748004    5.126665E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748005    5.126665E-1 -3.841086E-1
  748005    5.553671E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748005    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748005    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748005    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748006    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748006    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748006    5.553671E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748006    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748006    5.553671E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748007    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748007    5.553671E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748007    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748007    5.126665E-1 -3.416763E-1
  748007    5.553671E-1 -2.992440E-1
  748008    5.126665E-1 -2.992440E-1
  748008    5.553671E-1 -2.992440E-1
  748008    5.126665E-1 -2.992440E-1
  748008    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748008    5.553671E-1 -2.992440E-1
  748009    5.553671E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748009    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748009    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748009    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748009    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748010    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748010    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748010    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748010    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748010    5.126665E-1 -2.568118E-1
  748011    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748011    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748011    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748011    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748011    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748012    5.126665E-1 -2.143795E-1
  748012    5.126665E-1 -1.719472E-1
  748012    5.126665E-1 -1.719472E-1
  748012    5.126665E-1 -1.719472E-1
  748012    5.126665E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748013    5.126665E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748013    5.126665E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748013    5.126665E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748013    5.126665E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748013    5.126665E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748014    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748014    5.126665E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748014    4.699659E-1 -1.295150E-1
  748014    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748014    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748015    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748015    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748015    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748015    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748015    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748016    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748016    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748016    5.126665E-1 -4.465043E-2
  748016    5.126665E-1 -8.708270E-2
  748016    5.126665E-1 -4.465043E-2
  748017    5.126665E-1 -4.465043E-2
  748017    5.126665E-1 -4.465043E-2
  748017    5.126665E-1 -2.218165E-3
  748017    5.126665E-1 -4.465043E-2
  748017    5.126665E-1 -2.218165E-3
  748018    5.126665E-1 -2.218165E-3
  748018    5.553671E-1 -2.218165E-3
  748018    5.126665E-1 -2.218165E-3
  748018    5.126665E-1 -2.218165E-3
  748018    5.126665E-1 4.021410E-2
  748019    5.126665E-1 -2.218165E-3
  748019    5.553671E-1 4.021410E-2
  748019    5.126665E-1 4.021410E-2
  748019    5.553671E-1 8.264637E-2
  748019    5.126665E-1 8.264637E-2
  748020    5.126665E-1 4.021410E-2
  748020    5.126665E-1 8.264637E-2
  748020    5.126665E-1 8.264637E-2
  748020    5.126665E-1 8.264637E-2
  748020    5.553671E-1 8.264637E-2
  748021    5.126665E-1 8.264637E-2
  748021    5.126665E-1 8.264637E-2
  748021    5.553671E-1 1.250786E-1
  748021    5.126665E-1 8.264637E-2
  748021    5.126665E-1 1.250786E-1
  748022    5.126665E-1 1.250786E-1
  748022    5.126665E-1 1.250786E-1
  748022    5.126665E-1 1.675109E-1
  748022    5.126665E-1 1.675109E-1
  748022    5.126665E-1 1.675109E-1
  748023    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748023    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748023    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748023    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748023    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748024    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748024    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748024    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748024    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748024    5.126665E-1 2.099432E-1
  748025    5.126665E-1 2.523754E-1
  748025    5.126665E-1 2.523754E-1
  748025    5.126665E-1 2.523754E-1
  748025    5.126665E-1 2.523754E-1
  748025    5.126665E-1 2.523754E-1
  748026    5.126665E-1 2.948077E-1
  748026    5.126665E-1 2.948077E-1
  748026    5.126665E-1 2.523754E-1
  748026    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748026    4.699659E-1 2.948077E-1
  748027    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748027    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748027    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748027    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748027    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748028    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748028    5.126665E-1 3.796722E-1
  748028    5.126665E-1 3.372400E-1
  748028    5.126665E-1 3.796722E-1
  748028    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748029    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748029    5.126665E-1 3.796722E-1
  748029    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748029    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748029    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748030    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748030    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748030    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748030    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748030    5.553671E-1 4.645368E-1
  748031    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748031    5.126665E-1 4.645368E-1
  748031    5.126665E-1 5.069690E-1
  748031    5.126665E-1 4.645368E-1
  748031    5.126665E-1 5.494013E-1
  748032    5.126665E-1 5.494013E-1
  748032    5.126665E-1 5.069690E-1
  748032    5.553671E-1 5.494013E-1
  748032    5.126665E-1 5.494013E-1
  748032    5.126665E-1 5.494013E-1
  748033    5.126665E-1 5.494013E-1
  748033    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748033    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748033    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748033    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748034    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748034    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748034    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748034    5.126665E-1 5.918336E-1
  748034    5.553671E-1 6.342658E-1
  748035    5.126665E-1 6.342658E-1
  748035    5.126665E-1 6.342658E-1
  748035    5.126665E-1 6.342658E-1
  748035    5.126665E-1 6.766981E-1
  748035    5.126665E-1 6.766981E-1
  748036    5.126665E-1 6.342658E-1
  748036    5.126665E-1 6.766981E-1
  748036    5.126665E-1 6.766981E-1
  748036    5.126665E-1 6.766981E-1
  748036    5.126665E-1 6.766981E-1
  748037    5.126665E-1 7.191304E-1
  748037    5.126665E-1 7.191304E-1
  748037    5.126665E-1 7.191304E-1
  748037    5.126665E-1 7.191304E-1
  748037    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748038    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748038    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748038    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748038    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748038    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748039    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748039    5.126665E-1 8.039949E-1
  748039    5.126665E-1 8.039949E-1
  748039    5.553671E-1 8.039949E-1
  748039    5.553671E-1 8.039949E-1
  748040    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748040    5.126665E-1 8.039949E-1
  748040    5.126665E-1 8.464272E-1
  748040    5.126665E-1 8.039949E-1
  748040    5.126665E-1 8.464272E-1
  748041    5.126665E-1 8.464272E-1
  748041    5.553671E-1 8.464272E-1
  748041    5.126665E-1 8.464272E-1
  748041    5.126665E-1 8.464272E-1
  748041    5.126665E-1 8.888594E-1
  748042    5.126665E-1 8.888594E-1
  748042    5.126665E-1 8.888594E-1
  748042    5.126665E-1 8.888594E-1
  748042    5.126665E-1 8.888594E-1
  748042    5.126665E-1 8.888594E-1
  748043    5.126665E-1 9.312917E-1
  748043    5.126665E-1 8.888594E-1
  748043    5.126665E-1 9.312917E-1
  748043    5.126665E-1 9.312917E-1
  748043    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748044    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748044    5.126665E-1 9.312917E-1
  748044    5.126665E-1 9.312917E-1
  748044    5.126665E-1 9.312917E-1
  748044    5.126665E-1 9.312917E-1
  748045    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748045    5.126665E-1 9.737240E-1
  748045    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748045    5.126665E-1 9.737240E-1
  748045    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748046    5.126665E-1 9.737240E-1
  748046    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748046    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748046    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748046    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748047    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748047    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748047    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748047    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748047    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748048    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748048    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748048    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748048    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748048    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748049    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748049    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748049    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748049    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748049    5.126665E-1 1.058589E+0
  748050    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748050    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748050    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748050    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748050    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748051    5.126665E-1 1.143453E+0
  748051    5.126665E-1 1.143453E+0
  748051    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748051    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748051    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748052    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748052    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748052    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748052    5.126665E-1 1.143453E+0
  748052    5.126665E-1 1.101021E+0
  748053    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748053    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748053    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748053    5.126665E-1 1.143453E+0
  748053    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748054    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748054    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748054    5.126665E-1 1.143453E+0
  748054    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748054    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748055    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748055    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748055    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748055    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748055    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748056    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748056    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748056    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748056    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748056    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748057    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748057    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748057    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748057    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748057    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748058    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748058    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748058    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748058    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748058    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748059    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748059    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748059    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748059    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748059    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748060    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748060    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748060    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748060    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748060    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748061    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748061    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748061    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748061    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748061    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748062    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748062    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748062    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748062    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748062    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748063    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748063    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748063    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748063    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748063    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748064    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748064    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748064    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748064    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748064    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748065    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748065    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748065    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748065    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748065    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748066    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748066    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748066    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748066    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748066    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748067    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748067    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748067    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748067    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748067    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748068    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748068    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748068    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748068    5.126665E-1 1.270750E+0
  748068    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748069    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748069    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748069    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748069    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748069    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748070    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748070    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748070    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748070    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748070    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748071    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748071    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748071    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748071    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748071    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748072    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748072    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748072    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748072    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748072    5.553671E-1 1.270750E+0
  748073    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748073    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748073    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748073    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748073    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748074    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748074    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748074    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748074    5.126665E-1 1.228318E+0
  748074    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748075    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748075    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748075    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748075    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748075    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748076    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748076    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748076    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748076    5.553671E-1 1.228318E+0
  748076    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748077    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748077    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748077    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748077    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748077    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748078    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748078    5.126665E-1 1.185885E+0
  748078    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748078    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748078    5.553671E-1 1.185885E+0
  748079    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748079    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748079    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748079    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748079    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748080    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748080    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748080    5.553671E-1 1.143453E+0
  748080    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748080    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748081    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748081    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748081    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748081    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748081    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748082    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748082    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748082    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748082    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748082    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748083    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748083    5.553671E-1 1.101021E+0
  748083    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748083    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748083    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748084    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748084    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748084    5.553671E-1 1.058589E+0
  748084    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748084    5.126665E-1 1.016156E+0
  748085    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748085    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748085    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748085    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748085    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748086    5.553671E-1 1.016156E+0
  748086    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748086    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748086    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748086    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748087    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748087    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748087    5.553671E-1 9.737240E-1
  748087    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748087    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748088    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748088    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748088    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748088    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748088    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748089    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748089    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748089    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748089    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748089    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748090    5.553671E-1 9.312917E-1
  748090    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748090    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748090    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748090    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748091    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748091    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748091    5.553671E-1 8.464272E-1
  748091    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748091    5.553671E-1 8.888594E-1
  748092    5.553671E-1 8.464272E-1
  748092    5.553671E-1 8.464272E-1
  748092    5.553671E-1 8.464272E-1
  748092    5.126665E-1 8.464272E-1
  748092    5.553671E-1 8.464272E-1
  748093    5.553671E-1 8.039949E-1
  748093    5.553671E-1 8.039949E-1
  748093    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748093    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748093    5.126665E-1 8.039949E-1
  748094    5.126665E-1 8.039949E-1
  748094    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748094    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748094    5.553671E-1 7.615626E-1
  748094    5.553671E-1 7.615626E-1
  748095    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748095    5.553671E-1 7.615626E-1
  748095    5.553671E-1 7.615626E-1
  748095    5.553671E-1 7.615626E-1
  748095    5.126665E-1 7.615626E-1
  748096    5.553671E-1 7.615626E-1
  748096    5.553671E-1 7.191304E-1
  748096    5.553671E-1 7.191304E-1
  748096    5.553671E-1 7.191304E-1
  748096    5.553671E-1 7.191304E-1
  748097    5.553671E-1 7.191304E-1
  748097    5.126665E-1 6.766981E-1
  748097    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748097    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748097    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748098    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748098    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748098    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748098    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748098    5.553671E-1 6.766981E-1
  748099    5.553671E-1 6.342658E-1
  748099    5.553671E-1 6.342658E-1
  748099    5.553671E-1 6.342658E-1
  748099    5.553671E-1 6.342658E-1
  748099    5.553671E-1 6.342658E-1
  748100    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748100    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748100    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748100    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748100    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748101    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748101    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748101    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748101    5.553671E-1 5.494013E-1
  748101    5.553671E-1 5.918336E-1
  748102    5.553671E-1 5.069690E-1
  748102    5.553671E-1 5.494013E-1
  748102    5.553671E-1 5.494013E-1
  748102    5.553671E-1 5.494013E-1
  748102    5.553671E-1 5.494013E-1
  748103    5.553671E-1 5.494013E-1
  748103    5.553671E-1 5.069690E-1
  748103    5.553671E-1 5.069690E-1
  748103    5.553671E-1 5.069690E-1
  748103    5.553671E-1 5.069690E-1
  748104    5.553671E-1 4.645368E-1
  748104    5.553671E-1 4.645368E-1
  748104    5.553671E-1 4.645368E-1
  748104    5.553671E-1 4.645368E-1
  748104    5.553671E-1 4.645368E-1
  748105    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748105    5.553671E-1 4.645368E-1
  748105    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748105    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748105    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748106    5.126665E-1 4.221045E-1
  748106    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748106    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748106    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748106    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748107    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748107    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748107    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748107    5.553671E-1 4.221045E-1
  748107    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748108    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748108    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748108    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748108    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748108    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748109    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748109    5.553671E-1 3.372400E-1
  748109    5.553671E-1 3.796722E-1
  748109    5.553671E-1 3.372400E-1
  748109    5.553671E-1 3.372400E-1
  748110    5.553671E-1 3.372400E-1
  748110    5.553671E-1 3.372400E-1
  748110    5.553671E-1 3.372400E-1
  748110    5.553671E-1 3.372400E-1
  748110    5.553671E-1 2.948077E-1
  748111    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748111    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748111    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748111    5.553671E-1 2.948077E-1
  748111    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748112    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748112    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748112    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748112    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748112    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748113    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748113    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748113    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748113    5.553671E-1 2.523754E-1
  748113    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748114    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748114    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748114    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748114    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748114    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748115    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748115    5.553671E-1 1.675109E-1
  748115    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748115    5.553671E-1 2.099432E-1
  748115    5.553671E-1 1.675109E-1
  748116    5.553671E-1 1.675109E-1
  748116    5.553671E-1 1.675109E-1
  748116    5.126665E-1 1.675109E-1
  748116    5.553671E-1 1.675109E-1
  748116    5.553671E-1 1.675109E-1
  748117    5.553671E-1 1.250786E-1
  748117    5.553671E-1 1.250786E-1
```

Comment: This might be a question for math.stackexchange.com or physics.stackexchange.com--you are asking about best practices for fitting a curve, which is a big topic that has many real-world considerations, such that it's hard to recommend any one particular approach or function.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression

A good starting point might be:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

But be aware that in some sense, this question is asking "how do I do science?"--it's a big question with many answers and you'll want to ensure you're taking steps to ensure the fit you find looks reasonable, measure the residuals, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fitting an oscillating function can work but can also get difficult.

First, you need a function of which you think your data follows.
In your case this could be:

```
f(x) = A * exp(-b*(x-x0)) * sin(2*pi*(x-x0)/T) + y0
```

Now, it is important to get good starting values.

- y0: y-offset is easy, your data tends to y=0.5
- x0: x-offset is easy as well, read the first y=0.5 crossing from your data, approx. at x0=22040
- A:  is approx. 0.8 (0.5 to the first maximum at ca. 1.3)
- T:  between 22040 and approx. 23480 you count 10 periods, so approx. `T = (23480-22040)/10 = 144`
- b: For the maxima you have: `A_n = A_0 * exp(-b *(xmn-xm0)`. And hence, `b = -ln(A_n/A_0)/(xmn-xm0)`. So, take the amplitude of first maximum `A_0` and e.g. of `A_4` (of course, subtracting offset y0). And you get approx. `b = -ln(0.8/0.17)/(22650-22075) = 0.0027`

If you have an interactive terminal, e.g. like wxt you can easily read out these values with the mouse cursor.

Generally, if you run a fit in the gnuplot console it will either a) converge or b) run "forever" or c) stop with some error. In case of b) you could interrupt (pressing Ctrl+C) at least with gnuplot 5.4.1 and let you show the current values. If they are reasonably good you could stop and use these values as starting values.

If you have good starting values, e.g. with the procedures above, the fit might converge relatively fast. Actually, in the example below the parameter `x0` is not used for varying during the fit, but it could be varied as well.

**Script:**

```
### fitting damped oscillating data
reset session

FILE = "SO74694089.dat"

f(x) = A * exp(-b*(x-x0)) * sin(2*pi*(x-x0)/T) + y0

# starting values estimates
A  = 0.8
b  = 0.0027
x0 = 22040
T  = 144
y0 = 0.5

set yrange[-0.6:1.4]
set xrange[22000:]
set grid
set samples 1000

set fit brief nolog
fit f(x) FILE u 1:3 via A,b,T,y0

plot FILE u 1:3 w l, \
     f(x) lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
A               = 0.882658         +/- 0.002062     (0.2336%)
b               = 0.00278188       +/- 1.023e-05    (0.3679%)
T               = 144.17           +/- 0.02687      (0.01864%)
y0              = 0.508991         +/- 0.0003925    (0.07712%)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The exponential model approach looks reasonable to me. If you have an algorithm to find the peaks automatically you can put those into your exponential decay model without having manually select them. There are multiple ways to do this and I have had to "solve" this problem different ways depending on the complexity (noise, periodicity, etc.) of the input data. If your signal is pretty clean I would go with the following approach.

```
Vi = V - mean(V);   %remove the mean of the signal
[OPTIONAL]...Vi = filter(B,1,Vi);  %apply low pass filter (B) 
[Pks,Locs] = findpeaks(Vi,'MinPeakDistance',D) %assuming you have an estimate of the frequency, set the value of D to something like 75% of the expected period so that you only detect peaks that are separated by the expected amount
```

At this point, you could do some further checks on the Pks and Locs to qualify them, but otherwise these are the inputs to your exponential model.